# Display fallback image for a broken image

Tags: reactjs

Instead of a picture, the server sometimes returns https://i.stack.imgur.com/jLu4J.png (backend being repaired) this is why it doesn't work

```
<img
  src={imageSrc}
  onError={() => setImageSrc(fallbackImage)}
/>
```

option to set fallbackImage instead of broken image link. onError event doesn't happen, I checked. Are there options to fix it?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

> `onError` event doesn't happen, I checked.

I'm not sure what trouble you experienced, but providing a callback to handle the [`error`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/img#image_loading_errors) event works fine for images:

```html
<div id="root"></div><script src="https://unpkg.com/react@17.0.2/umd/react.development.js"></script><script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17.0.2/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script><script src="https://unpkg.com/@babel/standalone@7.17.6/babel.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/babel" data-type="module" data-presets="env,react">

const {useState} = React;

const defaultSrc = 'https://images.dog.ceo/nope.jpg';
const fallbackSrc = 'https://images.dog.ceo/breeds/cockapoo/bubbles1.jpg';

function Example () {
  const [imageSrc, setImageSrc] = useState(defaultSrc);

  return (
    <>
      <div>
        Fallback image used: {imageSrc === fallbackSrc ? '✅' : '❌'}
      </div>
      <img
        alt="dog"
        onError={() => {
          if (imageSrc !== fallbackSrc) setImageSrc(fallbackSrc);
        }}
        src={imageSrc}
        style={{maxWidth: '100%'}}
      />
    </>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<Example />, document.getElementById('root'));

</script>
```